# NSObject description and custom summaries in Xcode

Tags: objective-c, xcode, lldb

I override object's `-(NSString*)description` however Xcode always displays `error: summary string parsing error` in summary field in variables view.

My current implementation is the following:

```
- (NSString*)description {
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<%@ %p> x=%f, y=%f", self.class, self, _x, _y];
}
```

If I type `po objectName` in console, LLDB shows a fine output as expected, however Xcode and command `p objectName` always indicate error, so what's the proper debug description format to make summary field work? Worth to notice that the output of "p" command is the same as a summary message that you see in Xcode for instances of Foundation classes.

**Update:**

As far as I can see from "WWDC 2012 session Debugging in Xcode", custom summaries can be  implemented using Custom python script only. `-(NSString*)description` or `-(NSString*)debugDescription` methods are not connected anyhow to summary messages. I thought they are because I got an error displayed, but it seems it's a standard message for classes that do not have their own formatters.

Comment: You say "override" -- is this a subclass or a category?  And what is the superclass?

Comment: And I don't get you saying you do "p objectName" in Xcode.  In the Xcode debugger I've always done `po` for an object.  `p` is for scalars.

Comment: One thing to note, Hot Licks, is that "p objectName" will work for most of the standard Foundation objects (your NSStrings, your NSArrays, etc) because lldb has built-in formatters which know how to format the object without running any code in your program.  As Andy notes in his update, you can also write your own custom formatters for your own object in Python - it's pretty easy once you get the hang of it.

Comment: @HotLicks as Jason Molenda noted, p-command works fine for Foundation classes, but what is more important Xcode uses this output to display a neat summary message which is displayed in the variables tree while debugging. For example NSArray summary contains the number of items.

Comment: @Andy - The variable display so rarely works (and so often locks up the debugger) that I hardly ever use it.

Comment: @HotLicks what do you mean “locks up the debugger”/“rarely works”? Is this on a recent Xcode? Does it reproduce? Have you filed bug reports about it?

Comment: I mean what I said.  I'll grant you that I largely gave up using the variable display maybe 18 months ago, so I haven't tried intensively using the latest.  But it still seems unpredictable enough that I'm not tempted to try.

Comment: I would give it a try with the latest. And file bugs when it doesn't work.

Comment: @HotLicks unfortunately I have to agree with you regarding variables view performance on Xcode 4.6. But I think it's getting better anyway, I still use it for a quick look in a very basic situations.

Comment: I agree with Enrico.  If you had problems with the variable displays in Xcode eighteen months ago, you were almost certainly using gdb (where it was actually running code in your program to come up with those summaries).  This was problematic which is why lldb has adopted a different technique entirely.  Xcode 4.6 works well for the standard types -- if people see problems, please file a bug report at http://bugreport.apple.com/

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest at least:

```
- (NSString*)description {
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@; x=%f, y=%f", [super description], _x, _y];
}
```

So that you're not manually replicating the `NSObject` default and thereby blocking any non-default behaviour your superclass may have opted to include.

Beyond that, "summary string parsing error" is an lldb error. It's being reported by the debugger only. Per [its documentation](http://lldb.llvm.org/lldb-gdb.html), `po` is correct for Objective-C objects; `p` is for C or C++ objects. So you needn't heed that error — it's essentially just telling you that you used the wrong lldb command.

EDIT: for what it's worth, the method used by `CFArray` is [open source](https://github.com/opensource-apple/CF/blob/master/CFArray.c) and looks like:

```
static CFStringRef __CFArrayCopyDescription(CFTypeRef cf) {
    CFArrayRef array = (CFArrayRef)cf;
    CFMutableStringRef result;
    const CFArrayCallBacks *cb;
    CFAllocatorRef allocator;
    CFIndex idx, cnt;
    cnt = __CFArrayGetCount(array);
    allocator = CFGetAllocator(array);
    result = CFStringCreateMutable(allocator, 0);
    switch (__CFArrayGetType(array)) {
    case __kCFArrayImmutable:
    CFStringAppendFormat(result, NULL, CFSTR("<CFArray %p [%p]>{type = immutable, count = %u, values = (%s"), cf, allocator, cnt, cnt ? "\n" : "");
    break;
    case __kCFArrayDeque:
    CFStringAppendFormat(result, NULL, CFSTR("<CFArray %p [%p]>{type = mutable-small, count = %u, values = (%s"), cf, allocator, cnt, cnt ? "\n" : "");
    break;
    }
    cb = __CFArrayGetCallBacks(array);
    for (idx = 0; idx < cnt; idx++) {
    CFStringRef desc = NULL;
    const void *val = __CFArrayGetBucketAtIndex(array, idx)->_item;
    if (NULL != cb->copyDescription) {
        desc = (CFStringRef)INVOKE_CALLBACK1(cb->copyDescription, val);
    }
    if (NULL != desc) {
        CFStringAppendFormat(result, NULL, CFSTR("\t%u : %@\n"), idx, desc);
        CFRelease(desc);
    } else {
        CFStringAppendFormat(result, NULL, CFSTR("\t%u : <%p>\n"), idx, val);
    }
    }
    CFStringAppend(result, CFSTR(")}"));
    return result;
}
```

As with the other comments above, I'm willing to gamble that the answer is: Xcode's debugger isn't smart in any sense and definitely isn't smart enough to use the correct `po` means of getting an Objective-C description; if your object is an uninflected Objective-C object then the debugger isn't going to be able to figure it out.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. I just wanted to have sort of nice hint like the one that NSArray has, it shows the number of elements in array.

Comment: ... and you don't want to have to type `po`? If there's a difference then, at a guess, it's that `NSArray` is toll-free bridged and therefore it's not only an Objective-C object but also at least one other kind of thing.

Comment: Tommy, it's about summary message that is displayed in Xcode variables view while debugging and which can be very helpful, so helpful so you don't even have to type anything.