# C++: error: summary string parsing error

Tags: c++, constructor

I'm having a problem creating a new instance of a class I defined. I created a class called PointArray with the corresponding constructor as follows:

```
class PointArray {
private:
    int size;
    Point *points;

public:
PointArray(const Point pts[], const int siz) {
    size = siz;
    points = new Point[siz];
    for (int i = 0; i < siz; i++) {
        points[i] = pts[i];
    }
}
```

However, when I try to create a new instance I get an "error: summary string parsing error". I try to create the instance as follows:

```
Point p(4,3);
Point q(-1,5);
Point r(2,-4);
Point arr[3] = {p,q,r};
PointArray pb(arr, 3);
```

where Point is a previously defined class which works fine. Any ideas what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: Is that the entire actual error message?

Comment: I can't reproduce your error. It seems to be fine for me

Comment: This seems to not be a compilation error, but a message from lldb (the debugger) which is just a warning that a custom "summary string" for an object is malformed. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18090580/nsobject-description-and-custom-summaries-in-xcode).

Comment: You forgot the ; (semicolon) at the end of class definition.

Comment: molbdnilo is right. It is just a message from the debugger, but if you step over it, it works fine. But I would still like to know what is causing this message. Any idea what is going wrong?

Comment: BTW you are missing a destructor.

Answer (score 0):

This message is from LLDB, and means that your variable has been optimised out.

You can rebuild with -O0 which should prevent the compiler from optimising, however, your code will run very slowly.

Note that GCC has a compiler flag -Og, which optimises as much as it can without affecting debugging performance.

Clang also has this flag, but it's currently mapped to -O1 which means that some information will be lost.

Answer (score -1):

This seems to happen when the variable name is not entirely unique and the debugger has a different definition of it somewhere in its dictionary. Try to change the name of PointArray to, say, myPointArray, and the problem may go away.