# vscode hover debugger reports "error: summary string parsing error" for std::vector variables

Tags: visual-studio-code, clang, lldb, vscode-debugger

I am using vscode with `clang-14.0` to compile and debug my c++ program on Ubuntu 18.04.

I try to inspect an std::vector variable when the program is catched at a breakpoint.

But then the hover debugger reports "error: summary string parsing error" and doesn't print the value of varibles.

This problem only happens for `std::vector`. Everything works properly for other types.

[This SO Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28296967/c-error-summary-string-parsing-error) doesn't solve my problem.
How to solve this problem and make the debugger run properly?

Comment: The problem is that the debugger is not able to parse the summary string for std::vector variables. This can be solved by recompiling the program with debug information included.

Comment: Thanks for your reply ;-) Please let me add some more infos. 
1) All my programs are compiled under flags ` -g -O0 -fstandalone-debug` to confirm a `Debug` build. 
2) This strange behavior only happens for `std::vector`, instead others(such as other `Eigen` types).